# Sorting an array based on an attribute that may be nil in some elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, heterogeneous-array

I have an array of objects

```
[<#a star=1  val=1>, <#a star=nil val=3> , <#a star=2  val=2>]
```

i need the array to be sorted by time, then by val

```
[ <#a star=2  val=2>, <#a star=1  val=1>, <#a star=nil val=3> ]
```

but using the sort_by throws an error because the time is nil.

I am using an ugly way to sort right now, but i am sure there is a nice way to go about it

```
starred=[]
@answers.each {|a| (starred << a) if a.starred }
@answers=@answers-starred
starred=starred.sort_by {|a| a.starred }.reverse
@answers=starred+@answers
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
starred.sort_by { |a| [a ? 1 : 0, a] }
```

When it has to compare two elements, it compares an arrays. When Ruby compares arrays (calls `===` method), it compares 1st element, and goes to the 2nd elements only if the 1st are equal. `? 1 : 0` garantees, that we'll have Fixnum as 1st element, so it should be no error.

If you do `? 0 : 1`, `nil` will appear at the end of array instead of begining.
Here is an example:

```
irb> [2, 5, 1, nil, 7, 3, nil, nil, 4, 6].sort_by { |i| [i ? 1 : 0, i] }
=> [nil, nil, nil, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

irb> [2, 5, 1, nil, 7, 3, nil, nil, 4, 6].sort_by { |i| [i ? 0 : 1, i] }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, nil, nil, nil]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want the nils to appear first (zero-equivalent):

`@answers.sort_by { |a| a.star or 0 }`

If you want to make them appear last, you can replace the zero with a Max Int, but that feels too hacky. This might be better:

`@answers.select(&:starred?).sort_by(&:star) + @answers.reject(&:starred?)`

The answer provided by Nakilon is brilliant, though you're essentially sorting twice, on two different attributes. For most situations it's probably sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @amin-ariana, your solution worked for me and I think is more readable.

Comment: This behaves not as OP's initial code did for negative values like `-5`

Answer (score 4):

Just use `value.to_i`

```
starred.sort_by { |a| a.to_i }.reverse
```