# How to use sort_by with values that could be nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have an array of: `[{one: 1, two: 2}, {one: 5, two: 6}]` and I want to use sort_by something like:

```
[1] pry(main)> [{one: 1, two: 2}, {one: 5, two: 6}].sort_by{|x| [x[:one], x[:two]]}
```

However when I introduce nil for one of the values I get `ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed` :

```
=> [{:one=>1, :two=>2}, {:one=>5, :two=>6}]
[2] pry(main)> [{one: 1, two: 2}, {one: nil, two: 6}].sort_by{|x| [x[:one], x[:two]]}
ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: in which position should `nil` values appear? if you want to treat them as `0` it is as easy as adding a `.to_i` to the hash access: `x[:one].to_i` (assumption: all values are `nil` or integers)

Comment: @tessi was thinking just to ignore the value if it's nil as sometimes I need the values to be text or integers

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore". With `[{one: nil, two: 5},{one: 3, two: 6}]` should the result be `[{one: 3, two: 6}]` ?

Comment: in real life i have an array of hashes and wanna use it like    `array_of_hashes.sort_by{|e| 
          [
            e['description'].to_i, 
            e['c_currency'].to_i, 
            e['start_date'], 
            e['maturity_date']
          ] }`

Comment: Then I'd do something like `[x[:a_string] || '', x[:some_date] || Date.today, ...`. Thus, adding `|| <default_value>` to every hash access. This way you can control at which position `nil` values should appear.

Comment: @EkiEqbal When you are pulling data from DB, then only you fix it. So that you don't get `nil` value ever. You can do it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use this syntax,

```
starred.sort_by { |a| [a ? 1 : 0, a] }
```

When it has to compare two elements, it compares an arrays. When Ruby compares arrays (calls === method), it compares 1st element, and goes to the 2nd elements only if the 1st are equal. `? 1 : 0` guarantees, that we'll have Fixnum as 1st element, so it should be no error.

If you do `? 0 : 1`, `nil` will appear at the end of array instead of beginning.
Here is an example:

```
irb> [2, 5, 1, nil, 7, 3, nil, nil, 4, 6].sort_by { |i| [i ? 1 : 0, i] }
=> [nil, nil, nil, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475991/sorting-an-array-based-on-an-attribute-that-may-be-nil-in-some-elements).

Comment: A little cryptic, but it works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: And how do you put nil at the end?

Comment: Swap the 0 and the 1 in the block

Comment: For ordering DESC you can just do a `reverse`. This way most recent will be the first record and nil will be the last one. Don't do `i ? 0 : 1` as this will be ASC.