# Sorting using sort_by with nils appearing in the front

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Is there any way to use `sort_by` and make `nil`s appear in the front.

For example

```
[-1, 2, 3, nil, nil].sort_by &some_block
```

should give

```
#=> [nil, nil, -1, 2, 3]
```

It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475991/sorting-an-array-based-on-an-attribute-that-may-be-nil-in-some-elements) but the solution there does not work with negative values.

Comment: _Sidenote_: the accepted answer to the linked question perfectly works for negatives, even more, the answer by John is an exact copy of it.

Comment: @mudasobwa My bad! I am sorry. The answer is working for negatives. I don't how I missed that.

Comment: @Stefan, I am not convinced this is a duplicate of the referenced question. Even if it were, however, the (two) answers there do not span the range of possible approaches to this problem. Aside: I find the latter is often a problem when marking a question as a dup. Sometimes the referenced question has no good answers.

Comment: @mudasobwa, nearly. I am explicitly not treating `false` the same as `nil`, but there's not much point in since booleans can't be compared in Ruby anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Float::INFINITY`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#INFINITY) if your other values are numeric:

```
[-1, 2, 3, nil, nil].sort_by { |n| n || -Float::INFINITY }
#=> [nil, nil, -1, 2, 3]
```

Another way to write this is:

```
sort_by { |n| n ? n : -Float::INFINITY }
```

or more explicitly regarding `nil`:

```
sort_by { |n| n.nil? ? -Float::INFINITY : n }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> [-1, 2, 3, nil, nil].sort_by{|x| [(x.nil?)?0:1, x]}
 => [nil, nil, -1, 2, 3]
```

This avoids comparing int with nil, by takign advantage of the short circuiting behaviour of the `<=>` for arrays

Comment: I understand how `x.nil? 0:1` makes it appear before positives but don't understand how placing x at the end in `[(x.nil?)?0:1, x]` makes it appear at the front before negative numbers?

Comment: @Lokesh arrays are compared element-wise, i.e. `[0, x]` comes before `[1, y]` regardless of `x` and `y`. See [`Array#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you help me decide which way is better performance wise. This another or yours @Stefan?

Comment: Comparing numerics is undoubtedly faster than comparing arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
def sort_by_with_val_first(arr, val=nil)
  ([val]*arr.count(val)).concat (arr-[val]).sort_by { |e| yield e }
end

arr = [-1, 2, 3, nil, nil, -4]
sort_by_with_val_first(arr) { |x| x.abs }
  #=> [nil, nil, -1, 2, 3, -4]
```

I like how this reads: "Create an array comprised of the elements `val` in `arr`, then concatenate this array with `arr` with elements `val` removed, sorted as desired". Converting `val` in the `sort_by` to an artificial value that will make it work is, to me, aesthetically displeasing.